# R: How to remove element from list by value or type

Tags: r, list, loops, na

I have a list containing lists and NAs. I'd like to filter the NAs out, but I don't know the exact name or position of the NAs.

I googled a lot, but only found how to remove elements by name or by indexing, but this is not what I'm looking for.

Here's an example of how my list looks like:

```
example <- list(list(1,2,3), list(2,3,4), NA, list(2,3,4))
```

My output looks like this:

```
Name      Type        Value
example   list[[4]]   List of length 4
  [[1]]   list[[3]]   List of length 3
  [[2]]   list[[3]]   List of length 3
  [[3]]   logical     NA               <-I'd like to remove this row
  [[4]]   list[[3]]   List of length 3
```

I'd like to write a loop that removes an element from my list if the value is "NA" or the type is "logical". Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your data structure. With your example, the following will work:

```
example[!is.na(example) & !is.logical(example)]
```

It becomes more complicated if the sub-lists can contain `NA`'s that you want to remove as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `which` function to find the index of `NA` elements and then remove them by index:

```
example[-which(is.na(example))]
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I don't really know how tbh, `which(example$Value == NA)` doesn't work. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: You need to use is.na().

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: You don't need the `which`, and can simply use `example[!is.na(example)]`.

Comment: @JakeKaupp That's right but I think it's good to suggest different answers in this site and discuss pros and cons of each solution

Comment: I agree, which is why I commented.  Since `is.na` already produces a logical array for subsetting in this problem, converting that to a numeric index is a bit superfluous.

Comment: If this is an answer to your question you can accept it!

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, you're great! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This one is a simple method to remove NA values from R list

`example <- example[!is.na(example)]`